# How to add onclick event to radio button in Razor View

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, radio-button

I have this view. It's ok besides that I want to add: `onclick="javascript:SubmitClick(@Model.id, answer.Id);"` to definition of RadioButtons in it.

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Question
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    <h3> @Model.QuestionText </h3>
    @foreach (var answer in Model.Answers) {
        <p>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(b => b.SelectedAnswer, answer.Id)  @answer.AnswerText
        </p>
    }
</div>
```

Question and Answer are models which look like that.

```
 public class Question {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string QuestionText { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { set; get; }
        public string SelectedAnswer { set; get; } //this field is SET after clicking the radio button, I don't need this field ant this behaviour

    }
    public class Answer {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string AnswerText { set; get; }
    }
```

As far as I know `b => b.SelectedAnswer` this expression inside `@Html.RadioButtonFor` makes that after click the field `SelectedAnswer` in class `Question` will be set. I don't need that I only need that only one of those radio buttons inside foreach loop can be selected at the same time and clicking on them invokes `onclick="javascript:SubmitClick(@Model.id, answer.Id);"`. Also it can be done in obsolete way, just to make it work.

Screen which will help undestand how the view looks:

[image]

Comment: Why not just put this in a form element and post back? What does the `SubmitClick` function do?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Will the postback redirect me do different Action? I post an answer which worked for me. If you know easier way please show. Thank you.

Comment: Of course, if you want to. In your post method, save your data then `return RedirectToAction("SomeAction");`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I showed SubmitClick in my answer. It invokes method from controller which is no an Action.

Comment: @StephenMuecke No no it's exacly what I don't want. I want to update database when person clicks a radio button which will happen in `SubmitSurvey`(at the bottom of my answer) and nothing else so he/she won't be redirected/site won't be reloaded.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh it seems that my answer works but if you see easier approach please show me. Thanks : ).

Comment: Are you saying you want to stay on the same page? If so then using AJAX as you have is the way to go. But you ar setting both `questionId` and personId` to the same value (which is `@Model.Id` so there is no point posting back both values.

Comment: @StephenMuecke `@Model.Id` in javascript function is `Person.Id`. Thank you for comment finally sth I've done right : )...almost. Oh and you help a lot here-> StackOVerflow .NET questions : ).

Comment: There is no property `Person.ID` in you model. Your model is `Question` which has property `ID` so `@Model.ID` is the value of `Question.ID` which you are assigning to both `questionId` and `personId`

Answer (score 1):

The view:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Question
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    <h3> @Model.QuestionText </h3>
    <form action="">
        @foreach (var answer in Model.Answers) {
            <p>
                <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:SubmitClick(@Model.Id, @answer.Id);">@answer.AnswerText<br>

            </p>
        }
    </form>
</div>
```

The script function is in strongly typed view against `Person`:

```
 function SubmitClick(qid, aid) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("SubmitSurvey", "Person")';

        $.post(url, { questionId: qid, answerId: aid, personId:@Model.Id }, function (data) {
            alert('questionId: ' + qid + ' answerId ' + aid);
        });
    }
```

Method invoked by script

```
  public void SubmitSurvey(int questionId, int answerId, int personId) {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UPDATING DATABASE " + "Selected personId: " + personId);

        }
```